# Usage of a super.body() variable is illegal as it's considered "not declared"

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I extended the usage of my `virtual task body()` in a sequence class, and in the parent class declaration of `body()`, I declared a variable. However, upon using it in the extended class' `body()` , I faced a compilation error `Identifier 'q' has not been declared yet.`

Here is an example:

```
// Inside a base sequence class
virtual task body();
  byte q [$];
  ... 
  .. // rest of the code
  .
endtask : body


// Inside extended sequence class
virtual task body();
  super.body();

  q.push_back('hFF); // X Compilation error: Identifier 'q' has not been declared yet.

  ... 
  .. // rest of the code
  .

endtask : body
```

I cannot see any logical reason why the variable hasn't been seen.
I can, of course, declare it outside of the task scope as a class member, but I want to refine these minor holes in my SV understanding.

Any help please ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`q` is local to the `body` task in the super class. The `body` task in the derived class is a different task and hence a different scope. There is no way you should be able to see it from the `body` task in the derived class, any more than you'd be able to see it from any other task.

Comment: Alright, if I understood well: Calling `super.body()` doesn't merely copy/paste the previous implementation's code, but executes the parent's `body` as a different task in which its variables are allocated and deallocated only during the `super.body()` runtime ?

Comment: Correct. Class inheritance only concerns class members. `q` is a variable with an automatic lifetime,